# Can I save my selection (Theme switch) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a basic theme switching code using HTML and JavaScript. But if I hit back or refresh, the selection is cancelled and the page is back to normal.

Can I add any function in JavaScript so that the selection stays till cache clean or something like that?

```js
var x = 0;
var themeValue = 0;

function changeTheme3() {
    themeValue ++;
    if (themeValue > 2) {
        themeValue = 1;
    }
    if (themeValue == 1) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    } else if (themeValue == 2) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

```css
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 2px solid #1ECD97;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #1ECD97;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #1ECD97;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-button">
        <button type="button" onclick="changeTheme3()">Change Theme</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just imagining twerking code... I'll be a minute...

Comment: use html5 localstorage or cookies, then on load you can have an if statement to check if a cookie/local storage exists with a template saved, if so load that one, else load default

Comment: You'll want to use a cookie. `document.cookie`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making use of LocalStorage. If you want the user to be able to customize their experience, you need to save that somewhere. This is typically done through a Session or Database, however both of those are back-end solutions.

For front-end, you have the options of setting a cookie or using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). If you want the theme selection to be limited to a single session, you can also use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

For implementation

```
function changeTheme3() {
    themeValue ++;
    if (themeValue > 2) {
        themeValue = 1;
        localStorage.setItem('themeValue', themeValue);
    }
    if (themeValue == 1) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    } else if (themeValue == 2) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere when you load a page, you need to pull this value from storage. (Note, localStorage saves values as strings, so you may want to `parseInt()` your value when retrieving).

```
function loadTheme(){
    if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('themeValue'){
        var storedTheme = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('themeValue'));
        //do your logic to set the theme based on value
    } else {
        //do nothing or choose to set your default theme as the value into storage
    }
}
```

One side note, depending on which browsers you are supporting, you may want to make sure you're checking to see if localStorage is supported. It has good support for any modern browser.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that using sqlite html5 for example check this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/ :D

here for simple example sir

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

   <head>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var db = openDatabase('db', '1.0', 'theme selector', 1000); //db name, version, desc, size in byte
         var msg;

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS THEME (id unique, theme)');
         });

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM THEME WHERE id = 1', [], function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;
                var value = 'theme_1';
                if(len == 0 ){
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO THEME (id, theme) VALUES (1, ?)', [value]);
                }else{
                    value = results.rows.item(0).theme;
                }
                document.querySelector('#theme_selected').innerHTML =  value;
                document.getElementById('theme_select').value = value;
            }, null);
         });
         function update (){
            var selector = document.getElementById('theme_select');
            var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('UPDATE THEME SET theme = ? WHERE id=1', [value]);
                document.querySelector('#theme_selected').innerHTML =  value;
            });
         }

      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
        <select id="theme_select">
            <option value="theme_1" >theme 1</option>
            <option value="theme_2">theme 2</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="update()">update</button>

        <div id="theme_selected"></div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.